# Kendo grid, knockout vm and row templates

Tags: templates, knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, knockout-kendo

I have a KendoUI grid bound to ko vm

Due to specific requirements (icons in some columns, links , etc) I need to define the rowTemplate, which I define as ko template.

But I want also to have normal and alternate rows in different bg colors.

Because of this I defined two identical templates as below

```
        <script id="rowTmpl" type="text/html">
            <tr role="row" >         
                <td align="center">
                    <a data-bind="attr: { href: 'scrccc_checkEdit.aspx?id=' + CheckID }" >
                        <img src="images/icon-edit.gif" border="0" alt="Edit/View Check" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td data-bind="text: CheckNumber"></td>
                ....
            </tr>
        </script>
        <script id="altTmpl" type="text/html">
            <tr class="k-alt" role="row">
                <td align="center">
                    <a data-bind="attr: { href: 'scrccc_checkEdit.aspx?id=' + CheckID }" >
                        <img src="images/icon-edit.gif" border="0" alt="Edit/View Check" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td data-bind="text: CheckNumber"></td>
                ....
            </tr>
        </script>
```

Basically the two templates are identical, except the alt template have class class="k-alt" applied to table row.

But this approach is very bad, because it duplicates the whole markup for row template.

What is a better way to accomplish what I need?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

if u only want to change the style of alternative row, you can see sample here:   http://jsfiddle.net/P5EQt/

HTML

```
<div data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: items, rowTemplate: 'rowTmpl', useKOTemplates: true }"> </div>
<button data-bind="click: addItem">Add Item</button>
<script id="rowTmpl" type="text/html">
    <tr data-bind="css:{strong:id%2===0}">
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="value: name" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeItem">x</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Javascript

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.items = ko.observableArray([
        { id: "1", name: ko.observable("apple")},
        { id: "2", name: ko.observable("orange")},
        { id: "3", name: ko.observable("banana")}
    ]);

    this.addItem = function() {
        var num = this.items().length + 1;
        this.items.push({ id: num, name: "new" + num});
    };

    this.removeItem = function(item) {
        this.items.remove(item);
    }.bind(this);
    };
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

CSS

```
.strong { background-color:red; }
```

Using the knockout css binding with the condition of id (in my sample) that differentiate the alternative row

Comment: Thanks. However, this cannot apply to my case, because my ID's are not sequentially. I got another answer which pointed me to the right direction - to use jQuery($element).closest('tr').index(). The other question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457426/kendo-grid-ko-binding-and-access-to-row-index

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by using the "JQuery even" selector.  I added the code to the databound property of my grid definition.  Here's kinda what it looks like.

JAVASCRIPT

```
    var myGridDefinition = {
        columns: {...}
        dataBound: {
            $("#myGridId .k-grid-content tr:even").addClass("k-alt");           
        }       
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div id="myGridId" data-bind="kendoGrid: myGridDefinition"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also create an AltRow property and IsAltRow() method on the VM and use the css data-bind feature.

```
var vm = function () {
    var self = this;    
    this.AltRow = true;
    this.IsAltRow = function () {
         self.AltRow = !self.AltRow;
         return self.AltRow;
    }
}

<script id="rowTmpl" type="text/html">                    
    <tr data-bind="css: { 'k-alt': $root.IsAltRow() === true }">
         <td>
              ...
         </td>                        
    </tr>
</script>
```

I did also try to use the Computed Property feature of KO but it was throwing errors, not sure why.  But this solution worked out fine.